# FlushMode doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, jpa, type-conversion, seam, seam2

I have a problem with the flush Mode on a conversation:

If I set the flush Mode to manual in the @Begin(..) annotation, Hibernate still populates any changes on the attached entity directly to the database.

CustomerBranch is Entity

> @Begin(join=true)
>        public String addCustBranch() throws Exception {
>
> ```
>  CustomerBranch customerBranch=new CustomerBranch();
>  BeanUtils.copyProperties(customerBranch,doCustomerBranch)
>
> branchesMap.get(selectedBranch.toLowerCase()).getCustomerBranch().add(customerBranch)
>  custBranchesList.add(customerBranch); 
>  }
> ```

```
 @Begin(flushMode=FlushModeType.MANUAL,join = true)

 public void populateSelectedList() throws Exception {

    // PersistenceProvider.instance().setFlushModeManual(getEntityManager());

     ((Session)getEntityManager().getDelegate()).setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);

      custBranchesList.clear();

             custBranchesList.addAll(branchesMap.get(selectedBranch.toLowerCase()).getCustomerBranch());

}
```

In the above method, I add list to custBranchesList here I can't use any persist  still directly change reflect the database

componet.xml

conversation-timeout="120000" parent-conversation-  id-parameter="pid"/>

```
<web:hot-deploy-filter url-pattern="/*.mobee"/>



<persistence:entity-manager-factory installed="@seamBootstrapsPu@"

  name="entityManagerFactory" persistence-unit-name="mobeeadmin"/>

<persistence:managed-persistence-context auto-create="true"

  entity-manager-factory="@seamEmfRef@" name="entityManager" persistence-unit-jndi- name="@puJndiName@"/>
```

Comment: can you activate hibernates sql log to see what it is issuing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are already inside a conversation when your `@Begin` method executes? `join=true` just keeps the prior conversation untouched and does not change its flushMode even if you specified another value. To check try `nested=true`.